# Coherency measurement using Sentinel data on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-encoding

I am new to GEE. I want to implement the following equation shown in fig on GEE using Sentinel 1 two images.
The first Sentinel 1 image amplitude is |u1| and the secondary image amplitude is |u2|, and E is the expected value of some random variable. Here, * is complex conjugate.

How do I implement the below syntax in Google Earth Engine?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done in Earth Engine; the Sentinel-1 data is already processed to GRD, and no longer contains the complex components.

Comment: Thanks, then are there any other ways to measure Coherency using Sentinel images.